# DUI conviction in TN. What happens in CA

Tags: driving

Found guilty of DUI in TN and license suspended for 1 yr. My lawyer, nor anyone in TN can tell me what will happen to my CA license. What should I do?

Comment: I assume that means you have a CA license and had an episode in TN, and you're asking if it's enforced by CA.

Answer (score 3):

Tennessee is one of 5 states not party to the [Interstate Driver's License Compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driver_License_Compact). If the arrest were in a Compact state, then information is automatically shared, and California would treat the situation as though it had happened in California. [This source](http://www.tennesseedui.pro/) indicates that Tennessee can revoke your right to drive in Tennessee, and that is as far as they can go, but also they indicate that if your home state finds out, they may suspend your license. [Section 13352(a)](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=13352.) of the [California Vehicle Code](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayexpandedbranch.xhtml?tocCode=VEH&division=6.&title=&part=&chapter=2.&article=) states that the Department of Motor Vehicles

> shall immediately suspend or revoke the privilege of a person to
>   operate a motor vehicle upon the receipt of an abstract of the record
>   of a court showing that the person has been convicted of a violation
>   of Section 23152 or 23153

[Subsection (d)](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=13352.) further states that:

> A conviction of an offense in a state, territory, or possession of the
>   United States, the District of Columbia, the Commonwealth of Puerto
>   Rico, or Canada that, if committed in this state, would be a violation
>   of Section 23152, is a conviction of [Section 23152](http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/displaycode?section=veh&group=23001-24000&file=23152-23229.1) for the
>   purposes of this section

So it depends on whether Tennessee tells California. If they do, then under CA law, your license will be suspended. Under a [new law](http://www.capitol.tn.gov/Bills/109/Bill/HB2199.pdf) (June 9), Tennessee is required to report convictions to the [National Crime Information Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Crime_Information_Center), whereas previously some 18 counties did not report such convictions and arrests.